# Creating a new table that list the unique values of a Column from another table - Power BI/DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Im new to the Power BI environment, please go easy on me.

I have a table that has a list of locations for transactions. I need to create a table that list each location just once but will adapt as the locations change. Please guide on on where to start!

-JimmyD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new calculated table using DISTINCT('YourTable'[Locations])

[image]